# Migrate from ES1.6 to ES5.2

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hi have to migrate Java Source Code from Elasticsearch@1.6 to ES@5.2
Most things were pretty obvious, but there are some things I'm note sure about (becasue I'm a ES beginner).
The following is syntactically correct, but I'm not sure if it's also logically correct. Maybe you can give some feedback:

**First**

```
// old version:
CountResponse countResponse;
count = countResponse.getCount();

// new version:
SearchResponse countResponse;
count = countResponse.getHits().getTotalHits();
```

---

**Second**

```
// old version
esClient.prepareDeleteByQuery(SearchComponentsConstants.INDEX_CATALOG)
    .setTypes(type)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(
                  QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(), 
                  FilterBuilders.andFilter(
                      FilterBuilders.termFilter(CatalogDocument.CatalogIndex.CATALOGID.getIndexField(), catalogId),
                      FilterBuilders.termFilter(SearchComponentsConstants.FIELD_DEFAULT_ID, id))
                  )
              )
    .get();  

// new version:
DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(esClient).setIndices(SearchComponentsConstants.INDEX_CATALOG)
    .setTypes(type)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                  .must(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                  .must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                       .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery(CatalogDocument.CatalogIndex.CATALOGID.getIndexField(), catalogId))
                       .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery(SearchComponentsConstants.FIELD_DEFAULT_ID, id))
                   )
             )
    .get();
```

1) In many examples, I saw that `.setIndices(myindex)` wasn't used at all - but when my old code has this vaiable (`SearchComponentsConstants.INDEX_CATALOG`) I have to set it in the new code , haven't I?

2) Probably the new code is wrong, because I replaced `.filteredQuery(a, b)` with `.boolQuery().must(a).must(b)` **and** also replaced `.andFIlter(a, b)` with `.boolQuery().must(a).must(b)` ... so I guess the `filteredQuery()` replacement is probably wrong.

---

**Third**

```
// old version:
AbstractSearchParameter searchParameter;
SearchRequestBuilder search = client.prepareSearch(searchParameter.getIndex());
search.addFields(searchParameter.getFieldsToReturn().toArray(new String[0]));

// new version:
AbstractSearchParameter searchParameter;
SearchRequestBuilder search = client.prepareSearch(searchParameter.getIndex());
for(String field : searchParameter.getFieldsToReturn()){
    search.addStoredField(field);
}
```

I don't know that `.toArray(new String[0])` stands for, so I'm not sure if my replacement is correct.

Comment: You should be aware that using the internal java client API is deprecated in 5.x and not going to be supported from 6.x. You should transition to using the HTTP API.

Comment: Thanks for this information! But when I'm developing with java, what's the reason to not directly communicate via a Java API? Isn't a indirect communication via REST much slower?

Comment: Check here for what their thinking is: https://www.elastic.co/blog/state-of-the-official-elasticsearch-java-clients